# I don't know why i can execute this command line instruction

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2, command-line-interface

I'm trying to execute the command `sudo npm install -g ios-deploy` because i need it to deploy my application with ionic 2

Copy off my bash:

```html
MBP-de-Benjamin:ion-scanner-v2 Benjamin$ sudo npm install -g ios-deploy
npm WARN lifecycle ios-deploy@1.9.1~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) ios-deploy@1.9.1 ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ios-deploy-298c9491
npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-deploy"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Benjamin/.npm/_logs/2017-04-27T10_17_49_240Z-debug.log
MBP-de-Benjamin:ion-scanner-v2 Benjamin$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the open [github issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1910),

you should try:

```
sudo npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true
```